# Как сделать ярлык для bat файла на флешке

Tags: python, bat, embedded

Как сделать ярлык для bat файла на флешке? Я на флешке в папку python установил embedded python, положил туда свой скрипт gui.py (GUI  на PyQt5) и создал .bat файл для его запуска:

```
@echo off
%CD%\python.exe gui.pyw %*
@pause
```

[image: скрин]

Как на уровень выше **сделать ярлык**, который бы запускал .bat?

[image: скрин2]

Comment: пкм по бат- создать ярлык. и перетащить ярлык в куданадо

Comment: Для программы на компе (не на флешке) я бы так и сделал, но тут нюанс. Например, у меня на компе эта флешка находится под буквой "Z", а на соседнем под буквой "H"... т.е. при перетаскивании флешки с компа на комп буква меняется и ярлык перестает работать.

Comment: А хочется флешку вставил в любой комп, кликнул по ярлыку и программа запустилась)

Comment: Обязательно ярлык? Можно собрать просто маленькую софтину. Есть конверторы BatToExe.

Comment: Совсем не обязательно ярлык)

Comment: Я почему зациклился на ярлыке, потому что получается сделать .bat  не посредственно там же где gui.puw, т.е. если .bat поднять на директорию выше то со строчкой в батнике %CD%\python\python.exe gui.pyw %* он перестает работать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вы можете использовать cmd.exe.**

Просто создайте ярлык для cmd.exe (`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`)

А в параметрах укажите относительный путь к файлу (`.\dir\file.bat`) с аргументом `/K`

**Пример:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K ".\prog\test.bat"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не могли бы вы добавить скрин) А то я куда только не вставлял, у меня не выходит. Ярлык то я создал, а куда путь к файлу относительный прописать?

Comment: держите пример: http://api.hjee.xyz/prog.zip + скрин прикрепил

Comment: Спасибо! То что было нужно =)